# Russian characters are not displayed when i create an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, rails-i18n

rails 3.2

ruby 2.0

There is a form to create or edit a poll:

```
= f.error_messages header_message: nil
= f.input :question, input_html: { class: 'input-block-level' }
= f.input :results_hidden, as: :boolean, inline_label: 'Скрыть результаты до окончания опроса', label: false
= f.input :from_date, as: :datetime, input_html: { class: 'poll_date' }
= f.input :to_date, as: :datetime, input_html: { class: 'poll_date' }
%h3#poll-items Варианты ответа (не больше пяти)
.item_index  
  = f.fields_for :poll_items do |poll|
    = render "poll_item_fields", f: poll
  .links
    = link_to_add_association 'Добавить еще вариант', f, :poll_items, render_options: {class: 'links'}
```

**polls_controller.rb**

```
def update
    if @poll.owner_type == "Post"
      @post = Post.find(@poll.owner_id)
    elsif @poll.owner_type == "BlogPost"  
      @post = BlogPost.find(@poll.owner_id)
    end

    binding.pry
    if @poll.editable?(current_user)
      if @poll.update_attributes params[:poll]
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Опрос был успешно обновлен.' }
        end
      else
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { render :edit, alert: @poll.errors }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

When i create or edit a poll in the article, Russian characters appear as ??????????

If I create a new article, all displays Cyrillic. The only problem is creating or editing Poll (Poll).

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
#
# Install the MySQL driver:
#   gem install mysql2
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: db_development
  username: root
  password: "123" 
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I went through the admin console mysql. made the request: `SELECT * FROM polls WHERE id = 13;`

question: ????? 3

In application.rb:

```
config.time_zone = 'Moscow'
    config.i18n.locale = :ru
    config.i18n.default_locale = :ru
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    config.action_dispatch.default_charset = "utf-8"
```

**i created DB with rake db:migrate and after imported sql file in my DB**

Comment: you have to set locale for russian...

Comment: config.i18n.locale = :ru
    config.i18n.default_locale = :ru

Comment: https://github.com/yaroslav/russian - follow the article. It will help

Comment: Was the database created/migrated/`schema:load`ed after setting the db encoding or before it? Mysql can have default `latin1` on some setups

Comment: i created DB with rake db:migrate and after import sql file in my DB

Answer (score -1):

Try add this in top of your file
`#encoding: utf-8`

Comment: ruby 2+ does not need it